# Android studio. string.isBlank() doesn't exist

Tags: java, android-studio

In IntelliJ, I have an option to check if a string is blank or empty.

In Android Studio, I want to check is string is blank, but I don't have that method.

It only shows me `isEmpty()`. How can I get the `isBlank()` method?

Comment: `.trim().isEmpty()` should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`String.isBlank()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) was added in Java 11. As far as I'm aware, Android still only targets a compatibility level somewhere between Java 7 and Java 8 (and even then, not all features or methods might be available). See also [Use Java 8 language features and APIs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

In other words, you can't use `String.isBlank()`, you will have to write one yourself (or find a utility library that provides it for you).

Answer (score 0):

String.isBlank() is available only on java 11 but android studio use java 8 (or 7).
You can also check if a string is empty with the string.isEmpty() method

Comment: A blank string is not necessarily empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code TextUtils.isEmpty( someString ).
With this code you check if string is blank and null.
Means 2 solution check.